# Arrays of arrays or relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

The question came up after reading [Natural Language Analytics made simple and visual with Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/blog/natural-language-analytics-made-simple-visual-neo4j/) blog entry created by Michael Hunger

When a word is used by more than one sentence (or more than one time in the same sentence), this word will have two or more [NEXT] relationships. In order to know the correct path for each sentence we need to store the segment id and the position id [sid,idx]

Storing one instance is clear, it create an array with two values. But, **how do we add two or more arrays?** As far as I know, neo4j only accepts basic data types

Instead of using this solution, would it make sense to **store one [NEXT] relationship for each sentence path?** Of course this would generate a very big amount on relationships

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: In the referenced article, there is a typo on the last line of the query in the "I also want to sentence number and word position" section. That is, `r.pos = r.pos = [sid,idx]` should be: `r.pos = r.pos + [sid,idx]`.*

When you use the `+` operator on 2 collections, you end up with a single collection that merges the contents of the 2 original collections. So, if `r.pos` starts out as `[1, 2]`, then `r.pos + [3, 4]` will produce: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Therefore, the article does not an "array of arrays" problem.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam. I alredy noticed that, and that's exactly the problem. if I get [1,2,3,4] I don't see the way of knowing the correct path of each sentence. If I could have [[1,2],[3,4]] I see that more feasible to manage.

My suggestion is if it's worth to have one relationship [NEXT] for each sentence path. That would mean A LOT OF relationships, but I do not see other solution

Comment: It is trivially easy to get `sid/idx` pairs from a flat array. Every `sid` has an even array index (say `i`), and its corresponding `idx` value has the index `i+1`.